# Cordova iOS 64 bit compatibility

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, 64-bit

I want to have my current cordova pp compatible for 64 bit iOS. I downloaded cordova 3.7 into my project but I am unable to build. I am  getting the following error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RootViewController in RootViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DataBasePlugin in DataBasePlugin.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_LoginStatusPlugin in LoginStatusPlugin.o
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_CDVViewController._commandQueue", referenced from:
      -[RootViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] in RootViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_RootViewController in RootViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPlugin", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_DataBasePlugin in DataBasePlugin.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_LoginStatusPlugin in LoginStatusPlugin.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVPluginResult", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DataBasePlugin.o
      objc-class-ref in LoginStatusPlugin.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have also tried the steps from below link

https://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/xcode-5-1-and-cordova-ios/

I followed the below link to add the lib file to my project

http://outof.me/embedding-cordovalib-in-your-iosphonegap-app-project/

Please help

Comment: I'm having this same issue.  Any luck yet?